# Check if time ranges overlap and trigger error if true

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, checkbox

Sorry for the length of this question, but there is some background you need to know to fully understand:

I am building an event scheduler in Drupal 7 which allows users to check a checkbox to add an event to their schedule... and it's a mess. The checkboxes contain a value looking similar to `1404915600 - 1404917400` which represents `10:30am - 10:50am` which is the result of using PHPs `strtotime();` function like so `strtotime("10:30am");`

I need to check on the fly if the user checks another box with an overlapping time as a previously selected event and trigger an error if there is an overlap.

Currently, I am using the php function mentioned above to create the values in the checkboxes, and then passing those values to a javascript array on click of checkbox. The `id` of the checkbox is the url friendly name of the selected event, which acts as the array key, and the values are the selected times, so the array ends up looking like:

```
timeArr = { event-name-one: 0: 1404915600, 1: 1404917400 }
```

Each event has it's own key to simplify deleting (or unscheduling) events using Javascripts `delete` function.

Here is the complete code which grabs the checkbox ID and the times associated and stores them in the array:

```
var timeBox = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"].time, input[type="checkbox"].time2');
var timeArr = [];

// Listen for checkbox change
timeBox.bind('click', function() {

    var eventID = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    // If Checkbox IS checked
    if(jQuery(this).prop('checked')) {

        var timeStamp = jQuery(this).val();
        var newTime = timeStamp.split(" - ");

        // If timeArr has been set
        if(timeArr.length > 1) {

            for(key in timeArr) {
                if(newTime[0] > timeArr[key][0] && newTime[0] < timeArr[key][1] || timeArr[key][0] > newTime[0] && timeArr[key][0] < newTime[1]) {
                    alert("Overlap!");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    timeArr[eventID].push(newTime);
                    console.log(timeArr);
                }
            }           

        } else {
            // else timeArr hasn't been set -- so set it!                
            timeArr[eventID] = newTime;
            console.log(timeArr);
        }
    } else {
        delete timeArr[eventID];
    }        
});
```

I can't seem to get the newly selected event time to cross check with the current times in the array. They just get appended to the `timeArr` array as if the checks passed.

Am I going about this the complete wrong way or am I just missing something little? I've tried so many different things I'm quite lost as to which is the right direction to take. I am using Drupal 7 if that helps any.

Comment: remember that anything coming out of form fields is going to be a string, and so is anything coming out of `.split()`. `'9' > '44'` is TRUE in JS, while `9 > 44` is FALSE.

Comment: so do I need to use `parseInt();` to return an integer? EDIT: Actually, would I need to loop through the array and use `parseInt();` on each value?

Comment: yep. since you're doing operations that only make sense in a numerical context, you have to convert those strings to numbers. of course, most of your timestamps are going to be pretty close so it's not likely to be a problem right now. but at some point you will get bitten by this, and have no idea why `'9' < '8'` is failing.

Comment: Yes, you would need to parseInt to get an integer value. And for detecting overlap in JS, you would probably be best creating a JS Date object and comparing with that. The formula is `start1 < end2 && end1 > start2`. This will detect overlap in all 4 comparisons needed. You also need to decide if the exact start and end time is inclusive or exclusive. I.E. if something ends at 1000 and something else starts at 1000 are they overlapping for that exact 1000 minute?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn can you provide an example as to how I would convert these times using the JS Date object? Edit: No if one ends at 1000 and something else starts at 1000 that is not considered an overlap.

Comment: Then that is the formula you want. If you wanted something to be exclusive for that minute, you would just switch the `<` and `>` for `<=` and `>=` in the formula. And sorry, I don't have time right now to make up a real example (slacking off at work).

Comment: No problem, I to am at work. I've adjusted the formula and added `parseInt()` to every value in the array but it's still not returning anything. I'm thinking something is wrong with my loop and the associative array.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I was able to get it working (finally) using your formula. If you want to post as an answer I will gladly accept. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is `start1 < end2 && end1 > start2`. This will detect overlap in all 4 comparisons needed (below). You also need to decide if the exact start and end time is inclusive or exclusive. I.E. if something ends at 1000 and something else starts at 1000 are they overlapping for that exact 1000 minute?

The four conditions of overlap are:

1. Event1 overlaps the start of Event2 (Event1: 10am-12am, Event2: 11am-1pm)
2. Event1 overlaps the end of Event2 (Event1: 10am-12am, Event2: 9am-11am)
3. Event1 completely encompasses Event2 (Event1: 10am-12am, Event2: 1030am-1130am)
4. Event2 completely encompasses Event1 (Event1: 10am-12am, Event2: 9am-1pm)

The formula above covers all 4 possible scenarios.